# Why is the route I'm taking while tracing the code wrong?

Tags: java, trace

I am supposed to be tracing this code for my class but no matter how many times I go through it I seem to get the wrong answer.

The code below has me trace it and find the output. The route I take is as soon as I hit one(tweets) I jump straight to it before continuing to the for loop after it.

I get the answer

> Index0:a is -4 b is 1
>
> Index0:a is 14 b is -5
>
> Index0:a is 16 b is 1
>
> c is 6

```
public class Tweet
{
   private int a;
   private int b;
   public static int c = 0;

   public Tweet(int a, int b)
   {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      c += this.a + this.b;
   }

   public int getA()
   {
      return this.a;
   }

   public int getB()
   {
      return this.b;
   }

   public void setA(int a)
   {
      this.a = a;
   }

   public void setB(int b)
   {
      this.b = b;
   }
}

public class Homework4
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Tweet t1 = new Tweet(3, 8);
      Tweet t2 = new Tweet(-3, 7);
      Tweet[] tweets = { t1, t2, new Tweet(0, -5) };
      one(tweets);
      for (int i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Index 0: ");
         System.out.print("a is " + tweets[i].getA());
         System.out.println(" b is " + tweets[i].getB());
      }
      System.out.println("c is " + Tweet.c);
   }
   public static void one(Tweet[] tws)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < tws.length - 1; i++)
      {
         Tweet w = tws[i];
         Tweet x = tws[i + 1];
         w.setA(2 * x.getB());
         w.setB(-2 + x.getA());
      }
      tws[2] = tws[0];
      tws[0].setA(-4);
   }
}
```

This is my first time posting on here so if more info is needed let me know, I just need to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear about where you're making the mistake, so let's look from the top. I'm going to use the notation `Tweet(a,b)` for brevity.

Three tweets are created and put in an array. Since `c` is a static field of `Tweet`, I'll represent it separately:

```
c = 0
t[0] = Tweet(3, 8),  c = 11
t[1] = Tweet(-3, 7), c = 11 + 4 = 15
t[2] = Tweet(0, -5), c = 15 - 5 = 10
```

The function `one(Tweet[])` is called:

```
w = t[0], x = t[1]
w = Tweet(2 * x.getB(), -2 + x.getA())
  = Tweet(14, -5)

w = t[0], x = t[1]
w = Tweet(2 * x.getB(), -2 + x.getA())
  = Tweet(-10, -2)

t[2] = t[0] // the value of t2 is, effectively, discarded

t[0] = Tweet(-4, -5)
t[1] = Tweet(-10, -2)
t[2] = t[0] = Tweet(-4, -5)
```

So, using the format described by *Andrew Regan* in his answer, the output should be:

```
Index 0: a is -4 b is -5
Index 1: a is -10 b is -2
Index 2: a is -4 b is -5
c is 10
```

---

If you're having trouble tracing a block of code, some great tools are:

- Any good debugger will have the options to step through code and add breakpoints. If you're manually invoking `java` and `javac` you should already have [`jdb`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) available to you. [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debugging-your-first-java-application.html), along with any other IDEs will have debuggers baked into them.
- Another good resource (particularly for smaller programs) is a Java Visualizer available here: http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize

Answer (score 0):

There are three entries in the `tweets` array, and your code prints out `"Index 0: "` for each, so naturally you get three lines, followed by the final `"c is "` entry. You really were visiting every element, not just jumping to one.

I guess the confusion comes from not updating the index in the array, i.e. presumably you meant to have `System.out.print("Index " + i + ": ");` As so often, excess logging can confuse as well as clarify!

Then at least you'd get:

> Index 0:a is -4 b is 1
>
> Index 1:a is 14 b is -5
>
> Index 2:a is 16 b is 1
>
> c is 6

(Whether those values are correct is another matter!)